# Jenkins groovy if condition within steps does not work

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following stage in groovy script of a jenkins job":

```
stage('Remove servers') {
            when {
                expression { params.DO_REMOVE == true }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel RemoveSource: {
                        sh """set -x
                            export KUBECONFIG=${source_config}                        
                            kubectl get ns ${source_namespace} || exists="False"                                                    
                        """
                        echo "${exists}"
                        if ("${exists}" != "False") {
                            build job: 'RemoveFCC',
                                parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: Branch),                                                                                          
                                             booleanParam(name: 'build_ansible', value: false),
                                             string(name: 'pipeline', value: 'yes')]
                        } else {
                            echo "Server does not exist. skipped fcc run"
                        }
                },
                RemoveTarget: {
                    sh """set -x
                        export KUBECONFIG=${target_config}         
                        kubectl get ns ${target_namespace} || exists="False"                                               
                    """
                    echo "${exists}"
                    if ("${exists}" != "False") {
                        build job: 'RemoveFCC',
                            parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: Branch),                                             
                                         booleanParam(name: 'build_ansible', value: false),
                                         string(name: 'pipeline', value: 'yes')]
                        } else {
                               echo "Server does not exist. skipped fcc run"
                        }                     
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Even though `echo "${exists}"` prints `False` the if condition is still getting executed. I am not sure what am I missing here. Tried things like adding `when` instead of `if`.

Comment: Are you defining `exists` anywhere in the pipeline code outside of this snippet, or is it truly undefined?

Comment: Your parameter may contain whitespaces at end, try to use  `if ("${exists.trim()}" != "False") {`

Answer (score 0):

you change this variable from sh block so it changes "bash variable" and in if statement you check groovy variable

when you execute sh block jenkins will create bash script from it and execute on agent, next sh block will not get any of variables from previous block because of different shells

you can not set groovy var from sh block, you can only use output of sh block and parse it

```
stage('Remove servers') {
  when {
      expression { params.DO_REMOVE == true }
  }
  steps {
    script {
      parallel RemoveSource: {
        def sourceExists = sh (
          script: """
              set -x
              export KUBECONFIG=${source_config}
              kubectl get ns ${source_namespace}
          """,
          returnStdout: true
        ).trim() == ""

        echo "${sourceExists}"

        if (sourceExists) {
          build job: 'RemoveFCC',
            parameters: [
              string(name: 'Branch', value: Branch),
              booleanParam(name: 'build_ansible', value: false),
              string(name: 'pipeline', value: 'yes')]
        } else {
          echo "Server does not exist. skipped fcc run"
        }
      },
      RemoveTarget: {
        def targetExists = sh (
          script: """
            set -x
            export KUBECONFIG=${target_config}
            kubectl get ns ${target_namespace}
          """,
          returnStdout: true
        ).trim() == ""

      echo "${targetExists}"
      if (targetExists) {
        build job: 'RemoveFCC',
          parameters: [
            string(name: 'Branch', value: Branch),
            booleanParam(name: 'build_ansible', value: false),
            string(name: 'pipeline', value: 'yes')]
        } else {
          echo "Server does not exist. skipped fcc run"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```